# Is it better to check if some web resources exists in the server-side or in the client-side?

Tags: javascript, php, html, performance

Let's say I want to retrieve 12 images for a list in a webpage from an external domain using the ID of some rows in a database. For example for rows with id 1,2,3,4 the HTML in the rendered webpage will be:

```
<img src="https://external.domain.com/images/product/1.jpg" />
<img src="https://external.domain.com/images/product/2.jpg" />
<img src="https://external.domain.com/images/product/3.jpg" />
<img src="https://external.domain.com/images/product/4.jpg" />
```

But some of these images are not available, because this site doesn't have all images for all the rows in my database. I researched and I can check if any request returns a 404 error in the server side using code like this:

#### PHP code

```
public function existeRecurso($url)
{
    $recurso = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($recurso, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($recurso, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
    // Hacer la petición para obtener los headers y saber si el resultado será un error 404
    $respuesta = curl_exec($recurso);
    $codigoHTTP = curl_getinfo($recurso, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($recurso);
    if ($codigoHTTP == 404) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

After that I use the PHP function when rendering the HTML with PHP, if the image doesn't exists I'll replace the URL for a default one so the user can't see a broken image.

But there's also another way, serving always the generated URL exists or not exists to the client web browser. Then if the image is not found (the client web browser gets a 404 error and a broken image), use javascript in the client side to replace the URL for a default one:

#### Javascript Code

```
function repararImgRota(img, recurso) {
    img.onerror = '';
    img.src = '/images/default/'+recurso;
    return true;
}
```

#### HTML Code generated by PHP

```
<img src="https://external.domain.com/images/product/1.jpg" onerror="repararImgRota(this, 'producto.jpg')" />
<img src="https://external.domain.com/images/product/2.jpg" onerror="repararImgRota(this, 'producto.jpg')" />
<img src="https://external.domain.com/images/product/3.jpg" onerror="repararImgRota(this, 'producto.jpg')" />
<img src="https://external.domain.com/images/product/4.jpg" onerror="repararImgRota(this, 'producto.jpg')" />
```

Then here is the question:

**Which method is recommended for better performance in my web server so it doesn't crash because many users will be visiting the webpage?** (Let's say the web page listing the images from the generated URL will receive 100,000 requests every day).

Comment: Better performance at which end? client or server? Guess it would depend on which is closer to the remote server, the client or the server (which could change from client to client)

Comment: If you pass the checking on the client side (to the users), your server isn't doing all the look ups every time so it's better from your server's POV.

Comment: Probably best to do this lookup on the server end, and upon getting a 404, removing it from the db or notating in the db that it does or doesn't exist. That will of course increase load on your server though. In other words, **it depends** on what portion you want to have better performance, server or client.

Comment: @KevinB or still do it on the client and if it 404's then have the client notify his server to remove it.

Comment: but then you would have to ensure the client is authenticated because the client could just remove them all with a host file change.

Comment: If the images are not dynamic (sometimes exist and sometimes don't), then it would be best to check the images on the server and cache that result so most of the time you were just returning a cached result for whether the image exists or not.  The single server-side cache would then be shared by all clients.

Comment: its simple from a perf perspecitve. is it quicker to have ten boxes doing work for ten users or one box doing work for ten users? client-side workloads==free parallel processing. use the server for stuff clients can't do.

Comment: FYI, your client side code does not check if the image exists.  You would need an `onload` handler and an `onerror` handler and would then have to wait for one of those to fire to see if it exists or not.

Comment: @KevinB that would be possible, he could as you said before not remove from the server db but flag it as not available when it was last checked, or have some logic that when multiple clients reported 404 it would alert the maintainer of the db to clear out the wasted entries.

Comment: server-side would take 100,000*13 hits vs 100,000; do the math, less is good.

Comment: @dandavis I understand, I think it will be better, to let the visitors of the webpage handle the error with their browsers, so I'll use the client side code!

Comment: @jfriend00 The javascript function is just to don't let the users see a broken image that browsers shows by default, but yes, since I decided use the client side code, I'll do an ajax request to inform the web server the image doesn't exists and that the row in the database needs to get a new image (while the static content maintiner gets the images, I'll keep showing my default product image with the onerror handler).

Comment: often times, the best solutions will use a little of both client and server, it's rare that a one-sided solution will give the best cost, perf, UX, and maintainability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and most optimized way is to perform this job from server side with asynchronous services.

Put your php code into a file, for example:  cronscript.php  and execute it once or twice a day with
[cron jobs](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml) .  Your server will launch the tasks, and you will avoid checking on every client visit.

This cronscript.php must activate or desactivate flags of availability of images on database.

Comment: how many php setups allow cron jobs? i know dreamhost and goadaddy don't. plus that means you're always 12 hours behind if a naked lady accidentally gets served as a remote product image. with the client side code, you don't have to check twice a day; you never have to check because img tags already do that in an event-driven (vs polling) manner, so updates are near-instant instead of on a time-delay.

Comment: I already got some hints from some people that commented the question, I'll be using the code in the client side and using asynchronous http request to the webserver just when a given image is not found.

Thanks for your suggestion, but instead the web browser of the client will tell the web server when an image is broken and in the web server I'll check update the flags to know which rows are don't have available images.